# Integrals & The residual theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

"Evaluate $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^6}$$ using the residual theorem."

I am doing a intro course in fourier analysis and we are doing a short appendix on complex analysis, and I'm having some trouble with the residual theorem.

Now in order to do this we need to solve $z^6 = -1$ which gives us ${\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{6},\frac{7\pi}{6},\frac{9\pi}{6},\frac{11\pi}{6}}$

This is the part where I get confused. In the solutions manual, they begin by taking$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^6} = \frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{dx}{1+x^6}$$ and deducing that only three of those previous roots are in the "upper plane" of $C$ and is thus the only ones we are interested in. I realise this has something to do with the "extension" into the complex plane that we do in order to be able to use the residual theorem, but I am kinda lost on how it works in this case. Why is the extension to $-\infty$ necessary?

For example, in another integral involving a trigonometric function we made the substitution $z = e^{ix}$, and thus deduced that any singularities must lie within the unit circle $|z| = 1$. This makes sense, but I fail to see how one would see something similar for the function that we have here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let the radius of the above semicircle centered at $(0,0)$ be some $R>1$.

Denote the semicircle (positively oriented curve) be $C_R$.

From residue theorem you have:

$$\int_{C_R \cup[-R,R]}=\int_{[-R,R]}+\int_{C_R}=2\pi i \cdot (\mbox{sum of residues contained in the semicircle})$$

You can easily check that when $R\rightarrow \infty$ then $\int_{C_R}$ disappears. Also notice that your function is even. Could you carry on now?

PS. Your roots are incorrect.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I think I get it now. And yes, those roots are for the polar form, so it would be the roots of $e^{i6\theta} = -1$, no?

Now, the integral $\int_{Cr}$, this would be the $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{d\theta}{1+e^{6i\theta}}$ ?

Comment: You just found the angles. You need to input them into $e^{i\phi}$ and check which ones are located in the big semicircle.

Comment: Yes, that was a bit of a mixup. But yes, pluggin the angles into $e^{i\theta}$ and using the residual theorem works like a charm! Thank you! Reconsidering that integral over $Cr$, would this then be the integral  $\int_{-\infty}^{-\infty}\frac{dz}{1+x^6}$ but expressed parametrically in terms of $\theta$ from 0 to $\pi$?

Comment: $|\int_{C_R}\frac{dz}{1+z^6}|\le \pi R \cdot \frac{1}{1-R^6} \rightarrow 0$

Answer (score 3):

It's easier to integrate from 0 to R, then along the circle $z =R\exp(i\theta)$ from $\theta = 0$ to $\theta = \frac{\pi}{3}$ and then back to the origin along the line $z = x \exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{3}\right)$ from $x = R$ to $x = 0$. This way, only the pole at $z = \exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{6}\right)$ needs to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Use Residue theorem on $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^6+1}$ over $$\mathcal C_r=\{re^{i\theta}\mid \theta\in[0,\pi], r>1\}\cup[-r,r]$$
and let $r\to\infty $

Comment: Hmmm. Yes, this makes it clearer. I need to ponder this for a while, thank you!